# How can I partition N items evenly into M buckets?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose there are N items each with a weight value. I'd like to partition those items into M buckets (N is divisible by M) so that each bucket has the same number of items and the standard deviation of bucket weight is minimized. Is this a well-known problem? What algorithms should I look at? Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly what you're describing, but very relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Approximation_algorithm_approaches

Comment: This sounds like a generalization of the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Variants_and_generalizations). You could also view it as a 1-dimensional [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).